# Why would VAs that have many memorable lead roles take lesser roles?

Tags: voice-acting, mamiko-noto

***This centers around Noto Mamiko, but you can answer the question from a general/industry stand point if you want.***

Specifically since 2013, I'm noticing **[Noto Mamiko](http://myanimelist.net/people/40/Mamiko_Noto)** is pretty much a bit-character voice actress. She's not even "the MC's best friend" or anything.

I can think of 1 main character role in 2013 - Satellizer el Bridget in Freezing Vibration. That's it.
Even last year, her biggest role was probably Nishiki in Donten ni Warau, not even a main character!

In severe cases she is in the show for literally 1-2 episodes.

Why would this GREAT VA, who has played some very memorable main character roles, now be playing barely supporting characters?

Did she get married? Start TV acting? Any reasonable suggestion for this atrocity?

*Is it me or is **[Hayami Saori](http://myanimelist.net/people/869/Saori_Hayami)** stealing her roles?*

Comment: Mamiko is over 30, Saori is not

Comment: @ton.yeung that's what I was thinking but I'm hoping that's not true...Sawashiro Miyuki is 30 this year :(

Comment: Horie Yui is 38 and still working so but she's kind of an outlier. Either way, people in the entertainment industry rarely last past 30.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, voice actor has been idle reduction.
So, maybe television stations and offices is made to use the young voice actor.

----- Postscript -----
Although it is not a story that was only to Noto's,
in Japan, as the number of years that has been active as a voice actor is longer,
rank increases and salary will be higher.
So that, the request side want to reduce the production costs,
want to aggressively hired short activities years young.

It also is might cause.